# iOS Choose the adapted view

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm implementing a check module message in my app and I want some advice to choose the adapted view.

When I click on a button, it redirect to a view with all messages. I'll click on a message ( choose it ) and it'll redirect me to a view with more info about this message. I can then go back to the list messages.

Have you any idea about what view I can choose after clicked on the button ?